# How to detect the first access in a WCF project?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, .net-4.0, startup

I have a WCF project which has several services (e.g. .svc files).  The project is hosted in IIS 7.x.

I would like to run some code the first time any user accesses any of the services (because I need to run some code at that time).  I can't seem to find a global.asax kind of construct for this type of project, which would allow me to accomplish this task.

How can I detect the first time any user accesses any of the service?

Comment: Is there a problem putting your code in `Application_Start`? This is guaranteed to run once your solution gets the very first request.

Comment: @WiktorZychla You are right.  Once I added Global.asax, it all clicked into place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to find a global.asax kind of construct for this type of project, which would allow me to accomplish this task.

Since your WCF service is hosted in IIS 7 you could add a Global.asax and use Application_Start.

Comment: This will only work if binding is http , you need something diff if it is nettcp

Comment: @SurjitSamra, that's correct. But since the OP explained that he hosted his WCF service in IIS I assumed he is using HTTP.